# Using LOWER() in arcpy select by attribute

Tags: arcpy, query

I just want to include lower() in my query to make it irrespective of case.

When I use this I get an error:

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("BurrRidgeTreeInventoryMaster""NEW_SELECTION",' lower("species") like 'maple%'')
```

And when I use this I get everything selected, not just trees that contain 'maple%'

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("BurrRidgeTreeInventoryMaster","NEW_SELECTION"," lower('species') like 'maple%'")
```

What do I have wrong?

Comment: Try leaving off the quote marks around your field name e.g. `""" lower(species) like 'maple%' """`

Comment: That said, a SQL query ignores case, so it shouldn't make any difference

Comment: actually when I leave out the lower the query is successful but it returns 0 entries as opposed to hundreds with lower

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try leaving off the quote marks around your field name e.g. `""" lower(species) like 'maple%' """`

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("BurrRidgeTreeInventoryMaster","NEW_SELECTION",""" lower(species) like 'maple%' """)
```

The triple quotes around the query `""" this like 'that' """` enables you to include different quote marks in python as required without it breaking your code.

The Where Clause in a `arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management()` is a SQL query and case should be irrelevant here, so I'm surprised it makes any difference.